# Is it possible to freeze part of a spreadsheet

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet-function

I would like to do do the following thing:
I know how to use "freeze pane" that allow me to have a fixed part of a spreadsheet (the upper part) and another part that I can scroll.

Is it possible to do this on 2 axes (vertical and horizontal)
Something like this :
[image]

Comment: View->Split. This is a [su] question, and I'm voting to close it as such. It has nothing to do with programming, and while questions regarding Excel formulas can be on-topic here, normal use questions are not.

Answer (score 0):

If I think I understand what you're looking to do, you could hit the Freeze Panes button on the "some" that is just below and to the right of the yellow limits you have set (Cell H5 ?).

If that isn't what you're looking for, use the Split button located near the Freeze Panes tool.